# How to keep javax.xml.transform.Transformer from converting/parsing HTML-encoded characters

Tags: java, xml, xslt, coldfusion

I am using javax.xml.transform.Transformer to take HTML content and parse into an XML document (I am using the Crouton/TagSoup combination to do this). This, I don't think is all too important, though, as here is my problem:

I am dumping the output of the Transformer.transform() process and seeing that in the output, things like `&copy;` are getting converted to their actual symbol, in this case the copyright symbol.

Ultimately, this content will get re-saved as an HTML file, but instead of having the `&copy;` showing up in the file, it puts this special character, which given HTML standards, should not be used.

Is there any way to get the transformer to ignore already encoded HTML characters from being converted into their actual symbols?

Comment: This is no answer to your question, but why is it a problem to use the actual character instead of an entity like `&copy;`?

Comment: the ultimate goal of this process is to load the html (which might be malformed), alter it is using coldfusion xml support, and then write it back to a file. since the original file uses these character encodings, i would prefer the resulting file uses the same.

i've noticed that if i set the output method to "html", i get these encodings, however, i don't get valid xml (or rather xhtml) markup (so i can't parse it with coldfusion).

Comment: And why do you need these entities? Which character encoding are you using for your output files? UTF-8? ISO-8859-1? ASCII?

Comment: the files are being stored with a windows encoding, so i would assume the iso-8859-1 or something like windows-1251.

Comment: Again my question: Why do you need characters like `Ⓒ` to be represented as entity `&copy;`? If the characters can be stored natively in the output encoding you are using, they will be displayed correctly. There is no need for named character entities (unless you have some other requirements)

Comment: well, i guess one thing is that this html will eventually be loaded into a web text editor, and i do not believe that this supports these special characters; whenever you insert special characters with it, it always puts in the html entity...

Comment: Is this an actual problem or only a theoretical discussion?

Comment: well, i consider it a problem: i have html entities coming in, and i need them coming out.  the only reason i am parsing this as xml/xhtml over standard html is the fact that i need coldfusion to be able to parse the content, so i can manipulate it. in order to parse it in coldfusion, i need valid xml content.  and, i think i need to fix this at the transformer level because the transformer is handing coldfusion these utf-8 characters and not the entities.

Comment: CF's XML support isn't always great - I'd recommend just using [jSoup](http://jsoup.org) to do your parsing/manipulation, which is easier to work with, and may give the bonus of your `©`/`&copy;` issue going away.

Comment: Hi, I know you asked this question a while ago, but I am doing something fairly similar to you and have a problem - saxon is erroring because in my input file I have HTML entities that it doesn't recognise (it thinks it is handling XML). How did you set up your parser so it ignores/handles them?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following: Call `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ASCII")`. In this way, all non-ASCII characters have to use character entities.

Answer (score 2):

If it's XSLT 2.0 you could use character maps - I believe someone has created character maps defining all the HTML character entities.

Since it's Java though, there's nothing to stop you using Saxon, and Saxon has a serialization attribute saxon:character-representation="entity" which seems to do what you want (it doesn't understand all the HTML-defined entities, however, only those in Latin-1.)

Comment: Do you have a bit more information on this? I am using SAX2DOM as the "content handler" for reading in the XML data. Is this where I need to be looking for this "character-representation" thing? Also, I saw that Saxon has a transformer factory, and I tried using that but no go...

Comment: saxon:character-representation, like all Saxon extensions to the XSLT specification, is available in Saxon Professional and Enterprise Editions but not in the free Home Edition. If you've got the software installed and working, you can request it either in the xsl:output element of the stylesheet, or via the Transformer.setOutputProperty() API.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper solution to my original question, but this is a workaround that is getting me by.

Since HTML entities are being converted, before I send in the content string, I use a regular expression to "convert" the entities into another format, so the parser/transformer does not pick up on them.

Then in the outgoing string, I simply use another regular expression to convert them back into HTML entities.